# How do you download PHPSECLIB on CentOS7?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I have this php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
include_once("constants.php");
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP(Constant::QUICKCHECK_SERVER);
if (!$sftp->login(Constant::QUICKCHECK_USERNAME, Constant::QUICKCHECK_PASSWORD)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

And when I run it I get this error :

```
Warning: include(Net/SFTP.php): failed to open stream
```

The problem is that I don't know how to properly install phpseclib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd depend on where you installed it to. If you installed phpseclib 1.0 to includes then you'd need to do `include('includes/Net/SFTP.php');`. You'd also probably need to do `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'includes');` as well.

That said, if you install phpseclib with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) then all of this becomes a non issue. That'd be my recommendation.